# Como instalar o componente TIdHTTP no Lazarus?

Tags: object-pascal, lazarus

Notei que o *Lazarus* não vem por padrão com o componente `TIdHTTP`, diferentemente do *Delphi*, mas imagino que seja possível instar o componente de algum modo.

Como instalar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode ser instalado normalmente, basta efetuar o Download da versão apropriada e instalar!

[Referência e Tutorial de Instalação!](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Indy_with_Lazarus#How_to_install_.5B3.5D_Windows.2C_Indy_10.5.8.0_and_above)

Comment: O Download eu já fiz, mas não sei como eu instalo, é diferente do Delphi XE8

Comment: Como instalar tem na Referência que passei na resposta, How to Install